# Eliminate NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
    A        B       C      D     E       F
    NULL    1122111 NULL    0      NULL    XBK
    9226978 NULL    0       NULL    XGI     NULL
    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Now I need to collapse that to a single row with the below results:

```
    A        B       C      D     E       F
    9226978 1122111 0       0      XGI      XBK
```

I have no idea where to get started. Please help.

Comment: What do you expect for result if a column has several rows with a value?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow... PLEASE GIVE SOLUTION is not what we are here for. Developers are helping each other here. You need to show you have attempted something at least. Also refrain from ALL CAPS as that usually signifies YELLING! So what have you tried? Have you even attempted a query?

Comment: Not enough information. Is it possible to have more than one non-NULL value in the column? If so, what do you want to show for that column? Is it possible to have a column with only NULLs? If not, how are you enforcing this? What is the primary key for the table?

Comment: I am having case statement which results with this result set so I need single row  with value's. I am sure each column have single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(A) AS A,MAX(B) AS B
FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: According to me this creates prob in case of col e and f due to string values.

Comment: Coalesce will return result for each row. the o/p shown as single row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT COALESCE(A,0), COALESCE(B,0), COALESCE(C,0), COALESCE(D,0), COALESCE(E,0), COALESCE(F,0)
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: COALESCE Replaces the NULL with 0 . so it won't work